# IIS Rewrite Maps with Wildcard for Querystring

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Trying to figure out how to do wildcards for querystrings.   Right now this works, but it has to be an exact match.

I have this rewrite rule.

```
            <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects ReSv">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
            <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

My rewrite maps are like:

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
            <add key="/contact-us.aspx" value="/contact/" />
            <add key="/contact-us/request-information.aspx" value="/contact/" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Trying to get something like this:
/contact-us.aspx?q=t&1=2

To redirect to:
/contact/ 
And include the querystring? so..
/contact/?q=t&1=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please us **{URL}** variable instead of {REQUEST_URI}. Then Rewritemap will be able to wildcard the query string.

```
 <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects ReSv" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                        <add input="{Redirects:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

Comment: @bb2j3z I‘m so glad it is working. It is appreciated if you could accept it as answer

Comment: I did, upvote the answer to the left.... it doesn't change the number because of my reputation...   looks good to me.

Comment: @bb2j3z You should be able to mark as solution or select a tick for this answer.